# Taskbar window minimenu Win7

Tags: c#, windows-7, f#

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to use this menu through C# or F# in Win7. I even couldn't find how to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Introducing The Taskbar APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx) on the MSDN magazine, it describes about how to use the Thumbnail Toolbars.

> The managed equivalent does not currently appear in the Windows API
>   Code Pack, but it is planned to appear in a future release. In the
>   meantime, you can use the Windows 7 taskbar Interop Sample Library. It
>   contains the ThumbButtonManager class with the corresponding
>   CreateThumbButton and AddThumbButtons methods for controlling the
>   thumbnail toolbar, and also the ThumbButton class for modifying the
>   thumbnail button state at runtime. To receive notifications, you
>   register for the ThumbButton.Clicked event and override your window
>   procedure to dispatch the messages to the ThumbButtonManager class,
>   which does the dispatching magic for you. (For more details, see the
>   blog article [Windows 7 Taskbar: Thumbnail Toolbars.](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/02/26/windows-7-taskbar-thumbnail-toolbars.aspx))

```
ITaskbarList3* ptl;//Created earlier //In your window procedure:
switch (msg) { 
    case g_wmTBC://TaskbarButtonCreated
    THUMBBUTTON buttons[2]; buttons[0].dwMask = THB_ICON|THB_TOOLTIP|THB_FLAGS; buttons[0].iId = 0;
    buttons[0].hIcon = GetIconForButton(0); wcscpy(buttons[0].szTip, L"Tooltip 1"); buttons[0].dwFlags = THBF_ENABLED;
    buttons[1].dwMask = THB_ICON|THB_TOOLTIP|THB_FLAGS;
    buttons[1].iId = 1; buttons[1].hIcon = GetIconForButton(1);
    wcscpy(buttons[0].szTip, L"Tooltip 2"); buttons[1].dwFlags = THBF_ENABLED; VERIFY(ptl->ThumbBarAddButtons(hWnd, 2,buttons)); 
    break; 
    case WM_COMMAND: 
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == THBN_CLICKED) { 
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == 0)
                MessageBox(L"Button 0 clicked", ...); 
                if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) MessageBox(L"Button 1 clicked", ...); 
        } 
    break;
    .
    .
```

And in the second link it shows a C# sample using a wrapper library:

> As always, the managed wrappers come to the rescue.  The
>   ThumbButtonManager class (in the Windows7.DesktopIntegration project)

```
_thumbButtonManager = this.CreateThumbButtonManager();
ThumbButton button2 = _thumbButtonManager.CreateThumbButton(102, SystemIcons.Exclamation, "Beware of me!");
button2.Clicked += delegate
{
    statusLabel.Text = "Second button clicked";
    button2.Enabled = false;
};
ThumbButton button = _thumbButtonManager.CreateThumbButton(101, SystemIcons.Information, "Click me");
button.Clicked += delegate
{
    statusLabel.Text = "First button clicked";
    button2.Enabled = true;
};
_thumbButtonManager.AddThumbButtons(button, button2);
Note that you have tooltips and icons at your disposal to personalize the thumbnail toolbar to your application’s needs.  All you need to do now is override your windows’ window procedure and call the DispatchMessage method of the ThumbButtonManager, so that it can correctly route the event to your registered event handlers (and of course, don’t forget to call the default window procedure when you’re done!):

if (_thumbButtonManager != null)
    _thumbButtonManager.DispatchMessage(ref m);

base.WndProc(ref m);
```